# Python json parser problem with whitespaces

Tags: python, json, string, parsing, integer

I'm working with some JSON data which I get from an API. But when I try to parse it using the python json parser the resulting values within quotes that has a whitespace gets parsed incorrectly.

For example:

From the response.text from the api I get the following part: "value":"4 685",
After parsing it turns into 'value': '4\xa0685'

I understand that I could manually take away the \xa0 and get the result but it seems like a weird solution.

the code:

```
response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion that seems to be an issue with encoding.

From requests module documentation

> When you make a request, Requests makes educated guesses about the
>   encoding of the response based on the HTTP headers. The text encoding
>   guessed by Requests is used when you access r.text. You can find out
>   what encoding Requests is using, and change it, using the r.encoding
>   property

Can you check the headers to check which charset is set and convert to proper encoding using `encode()`?

Optionally you can change the encoding of response to 'utf-8' before converting to JSON.

```
response = requests.get(url)
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
data = json.loads(response.text)
```

reference: 
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content

Answer (score 0):

`4 685` is not a number formated correctly for the parser to read it as a integer